# Using width=100% giving strange scrollbar issues

Tags: html, css

On my page I have several elements defined to be 100% of the window's width, however I'm getting unexpected results from some of the divs. For example, if I use console.log to print out the window.innerWidth, I get a value of 1541, but when inspecting the html, body, and a few other divs that are set to width=100%, their calculated widths are 1526.

Even stranger, I'll begin to see a horizontal scroll bar before the content begins to be too wide for the browser and some of the elements span past the scrollbar and some do not.

A very strange issue indeed, please have a look at the site if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be wonderful:

http://www.newnoisegroup.org

Comment: Please reduce it to a simpler test case; “debug my website” questions are obsolete very fast. Anyways, keep in mind that, by default, `width` does not include padding, margin, and border. You shouldn’t need too much `width: 100%;` in the first place…

Comment: Are you seeing the inconsistent width calculations when checking in just one browser? I've found width can be inconsistent in FF vs. Chrome

Comment: I'm seeing it in Safari, Chrome, and Safari for iPad and iPhone, haven't checked FF yet.

Answer (score 3):

`div` elements (and other `display:block` elements) default to stretching to the width of their container anyway, so setting `width:100%` for them is usually unnecessary anyway.

However if you do set them to `width:100%`, you can get issues like this because `width:100%` is not the same as `stretch to full width`.

The difference is that in the standard box model, the `width` of an element is the *inner* width; the border and margin are added on outside of box.

Therefore, if you have a box with width:100%`and, for example,`border:1px`and`margin:5px`, you will get 100% width plus an additional 12 pixels. This will clearly give you unwanted scroll bars as the box is wider than its container.

There are two solutions here:

1. Use `width:auto` or no `width` setting at all rather than `width:100%`.
2. Use `box-sizing:border-box` to switch the box model so that the border and margin are inside the `width`, so that `width:100%` will then produce a box that is actually 100% of the width of its container.

Hope that helps.

Comment: width: auto; worked for me when the div had some padding at right and left.

Answer (score 1):

using `box-sizing` can fix width issues.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
```

It often resolves issues with `width` and `margin`/`padding`