# Why are the margins not working properly?

Tags: html, css

In this page, why is only the top margin and left margin is visible? What happens to the right margin and bottom margin?

```css
html,
body {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- body element added automatically -->
<main>Wtf</main>
```

And if I make some changes which fixes the margins:

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- body element added automatically -->
<main>Wtf</main>
```

Where did the bottom margin go? Why is it not visible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources (like JSFiddle) to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead (use the Edit button not the Comment button). Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2b0sfw8j/ jsfiddle

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Then put your code in your question using the editor. The tools are not complicated. Information doesn't belong down here in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using width=100% giving strange scrollbar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666578/using-width-100-giving-strange-scrollbar-issues)

Comment: Thanks for editing it isherwood, I will take a look at that, this is my first time asking please don't mind.

Comment: Not really, I think I didn't define my problem correctly, Lemme edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things - browser's can put default margins on eg. body (in this case 8px when I look) so having a body with width 100% (the viewport) causes overflow because with that margin things are now too big. Then secondly, the child element gets a 24px margin and that is shown top and left but on the right and bottom there is no room for it.

If we don't constrain the body size to 100% (100vw) but make main into 100vw width and 100vh height see what happens:

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  rheight: 100%;
  rwidth: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- body element added automatically -->
<main>Wtf</main>
```

When you scroll you can see that the whole main is there plus its margins.

If you want everything to fit within the viewport but main to have margins of 24px still then its width and height can be calculated e.g. calc(100% - (2 * 24px))

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - (2 * 24px));
  width: calc(100% - (2 * 24px));
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- body element added automatically -->
<main>Wtf</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `box-sizing: border-box;`, which makes it so the `padding` and `border` are considered included within the `width` & `height` properties.

This is a good choice in general, but it is important to realize that unlike `padding` and `border`, it does not affect `margin`.

-

Because of this, since your inner element has a width of 100% plus a 24px margin, it will always be too big and cause a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Yes I tried using that to fix this but didn't work

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The box-sizing isn´t related, as it only affects padding/border not margin. You're using margin. You either have to replace your `margin` by a `border` (which would be affected by the border-box sizing), or reduce the width.

Comment: I mean let's say I removed the box-sizing since it isn't necessary but why isn't there equal margin on all the sides?

Comment: The box-sizing is a good property to use, it is just not related to the problem. The same goes for vh vs percentages, unrelated here. The problem is you're asking for something impossible. Imagine the browser canvas is 500px by 500px. This means your `body.height=100%=500px`. You also say the `main.height=100% (of its 500px parent)=500px`. You then try to add that 500px `main` element into the 500px `body`, with 24px margin above it , and 24px margin below it. 548px doesnt fit within 500px.

Comment: No problem. The fact i brought up `box-sizing` is because if you were using `padding` or `border` (instead of `margin`), then the result **would** change depending on which of the 2 `box-sizing` options you use. `margin` however, is never included in width/height, no matter which `box-sizing` you use.

Answer (score 0):

These could be of help:

1. [Collapsing Margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
2. [Break Margins](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-break-3/#break-margins)

My experience taught me:

1. for spacing **around** a single element => use paddings.
2. for spacing **between** multiple elements => use margins.
3. for centering horizontally => use margins.
4. for centering vertically => `position/transform` + `top/left/right/bottom` OR `flex/align-items`
5. for organising multiple elements with common alignments => `flex/align-items`
6. For self alignments => use `position/transform` and `top/left/right/bottom`